# Proof: If $A\subseteq X$ Is Connected Then $A\subseteq U$ or $A\subseteq V$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topologic space. Let $U,V\subseteq X$ be open, disjoint such that $U\cup V=X$ and let $A\subseteq X$ be connected. Then $A\subseteq U$ or $A\subseteq V$

Let assume that $A\not\subseteq U$ or $A\not\subseteq V$, because $U\cup V=X$ we get $A\cap V\neq \emptyset$ and $A\cap U\neq \emptyset$ corresponding.
$A\cap V$ and $A\cap U$ are open, non empty, disjoint sets such that:
$$(A\cap U) \cup (A\cap V)=A\cap(U\cup V)=A\cap X = A$$

Therefore $A$ is not connected. Contradiction

Why can we assume that  $A\cap V$ and $A\cap U$ are open? I understand that $U,V$ are open, but why $A$ is open?

Comment: Sets aren't open. They're open *in* a space. In this case, $A\cap U$ need not be open in $X$, but it is open in $A$ (by definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subspace $A$ is connected iff we cannot write it as a *disjoint* union of *relatively open* (i.e. open in $A$!) subsets that are *both non-empty*.

$A \cap U$ and $V \cap A$ are by definition open in $A$ and they are disjoint (as $U$ and $V$ are) and they cover $A$ (all we need for that is $A \subseteq U \cup V$ and that is certainly the case here). So as $A$ is given to be connected one of them *must* be empty. If $A \cap U = \emptyset$ so $A \cap V = A$ which implies $A \subseteq V$. Likewise if $A \cap V = \emptyset$, $A \subseteq U$ and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

When you speak about connectedness, you have to consider the *subspace* topology on $A$. Because $U,V$ are open in $X$, then by definition of this topology, $A \cap U$ and $A \cap V$ are open in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

They are open in $A$, by the definition of the subspace topology.  $A$ is not necessarily open in $X$; but it is open in itself.